# .NET Core e Mono: desenvolvimento de aplicações para Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, mono

Atualmente tenho precisado desenvolver aplicações (*desktop*) para Linux, e um dos requisitos é que teria que ser usando *C#*.

E pesquisando/testando, fiquei com duas opções:

- *.NET Core* ou
- *Mono*.

Ao que usei do *Mono*, perco muito dos recursos gráficos (aquele visual  *Windows 98*), e pela [FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/winforms/) deu pra perceber que os recursos gráficos (Winforms) podem ser um pouco problemáticos.

Com relação ao .NET Core não tenho experiência prática ainda, apenas alguns testes de configuração e instalação.

Quais as principais diferenças entre essas duas abordagens (.NET Core ou Mono)? Existem casos em que é mais recomendado um ao outro?

No [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-NET-Core-and-Mono#) e no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738106/net-core-vs-mono) encontrei *threads* interessantes sobre o assunto.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738106/net-core-vs-mono

Comment: Não sou muito familiar com interface gráfica no  Linux, mas creio que o caminho seria um wrapper do gtk ou do qt, ou até mesmo uma interface web. System.Windows.Forms e WPF não são compatíveis, mas existem planos da MS em portar a interface: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/19216/wpf-in-linux.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta já não faz muito sentido mais, veja [O .NET Framework está morto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101). O destino do Mono é o mesmo.

Eu prefiro o .NET Core que já tem uma comunidade maior e o suporte prioritário da Microsoft. Ele tem inúmeras vantagens e poucas desvantagens comparando com o Mono. E quase tudo o que tem a mais no Mono pode ser transposto para o .NET Core.

O Mono só deveria ser usado onde o Core não consegue ser usado, o que é bem raro hoje em dia. Não temos como saber se é seu caso, nem você saberá dizer de antemão, mas só pense nele se tiver um bom motivo.

Quanto à GUI, dá na mesma, no Linux as opções são idênticas, ou seja, todas feitas para o Mono. Não há expectativas de uso das GUIs do Windows no Linux por razões óbvias.

O resto são pequenos detalhes pouco importantes. As respostas do Quora são questionáveis. Tem erros na resposta mais votada do SOen (pelo menos na versão original). A maioria é bem complicada.

Comment: Não tinha levado em consideração a questão do suporte pro caso do *.NET*, é um ponto bem importante, obrigado.